# Change language on the fly codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, internationalization

I have a welcome controller, which allows the user to choose a language (en or fr) which then points to it's respective controller (en or fr) so the url looks like this www.xxx.com/en/func/func. I would like so that there can be a link that can change the language, and I would like it to switch language but stay at the same page. Simply grab the corresponding language lines from the proper language files.

Which is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use routing for this, in your `routes.php` you should add this:

```
$route['([a-z]{2})/(:any)'] = 'yourdefaulthomecontroller/$2/lang/$1'; // rearrange as you like
```

Then in your default controller you could find the rsegment and use it against whatever you need.

```
print_r($this->uri->rsegment_array()); // This will print out the routes
```

In practical:

```
if($this->uri->rsegment(3) == 'lang' && $this->uri->rsegment(4))
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: This is what I did

`<!--- Language Chooser -->
<?php 
if ($this->uri->segment(1) === 'fr')
{
    $this->lang->load('fr', 'french');
}
else
{
    $this->lang->load('en', 'english');
}
?>
<!-- End of Language Chooser -->`


Then, simply 

`<?php echo $this->lang->line('hello'); ?>`

Where 'hello' is the line in the language file I want to pull

Answer (score 0):

the easy way is to add to your change language links variables you need to be saved after page reload

so look in your code for all navigation variables and simply add them to your language links

Answer (score 0):

How do you currently achieve the I18N?
Whenever I deal with multiple languages on a site I use parser class as it allows to add multiple languages very easily.

By using that it is quite easy to switch languages by determining language requested in the url.

If by "on the fly" you mean changing the language without realoading the page then that's a whole other thing.

Comment: The page would have to reload. Basically, a link, but I would like the page to be the same, just the words be pulled from the right language's file